# Постепенная подгрузка аудио при прослушивании

Tags: html5, frontend, потоки-данных, backend, web-audio

У меня есть проект с музыкой. (**Nuxt.js** + **PHP** на беке)

Сейчас у меня прослушивание трека идет только после полной загрузки файла mp3 при нажатии на красную кнопку. На бекенде просто отдаю целиковый файл.

Мне надо чтобы было как например, в **ВКонтакте**,
то есть если мы нажали кнопку прослушать, то подгрузилось **30 секунд** аудио (*а не весь mp3*), и оно сразу стало воспроизводиться и далее постепенно подгружалось.

Картинка ниже для наглядности проекта.

Какие есть способы такое реализовать в 2023?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]